# How to avoid loading my site in iFrame

Tags: jquery, security, iframe, frame

To avoid XRS, I would check where my site load, in the main window or in frame or iframe. 
Is it possible to check on server side from where request, that is a browser address line or src attribute of frame or iframe. 
If is not possible on server side, then how is possible with jQuery? 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5):

Use a frame killer.

CSS:

```
<style>
html{display:none;}
</style>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function frameKiller() {
    if (self == top) {
        document.documentElement.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        top.location = self.location;
    }
}
</script>
```

Then call the framekiller function on the pages you want to protect

Jquery:

```
$(function () {
    frameKiller();
});
```

Complete Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

<style>
html{display:none;}
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

Page Content

<script>
function frameKiller() {
    if (self == top) {
        document.documentElement.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        top.location = self.location;
    }
}

$(function () {
    frameKiller();
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

To test, try to load this page into an iframe from a different domain.

Comment: Please explain how does this work. Or give some helpful links.

Comment: Added an example of how to use. For another reference of how to call javascript functions go here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Comment: Ok, thanks. Had been having trouble understanding it before. Now it's good !